# Изменение QLabel при вводе числа в QSpinBox

Tags: python, pyqt, сигналы-слоты, qlabel, qspinbox

Хочу сделать что-то похожее на это:

Есть `spinBox` с допустимостью ввода числ от `1` до `5`,

```
при вводе 1 в spinBox в label текст должен меняться на 20, 
при вводе 2 в spinBox в label текст должен меняться на 40,
при вводе 3 в spinBox в label текст должен меняться на 60, 
при вводе 4 в spinBox в label текст должен меняться на 80, 
при вводе 5 в spinBox в label текст должен меняться на 100
```

и если в `spibBox` введено число **`0`**, то в `label` текст должен быть "Ошибка ...".

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets  
        
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(298, 313)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(298, 313))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(298, 313))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 190, 311, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.spinBox.setFrame(False)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(5)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 109, 301, 21))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите число от 1 до 5"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.setupUi(self)      

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QSpinBox::valueChanged(int i)
>
> Этот сигнал испускается всякий раз, когда значение спин-бокса изменяется. Целочисленное значение нового значения передается в i.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets  

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(298, 313)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(298, 313))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(298, 313))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 190, 311, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(40)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.spinBox.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 80, 181, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.spinBox.setFont(font)
        self.spinBox.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.spinBox.setFrame(False)
        self.spinBox.setButtonSymbols(QtWidgets.QAbstractSpinBox.NoButtons)
        self.spinBox.setMinimum(1)
        self.spinBox.setMaximum(5)
        self.spinBox.setObjectName("spinBox")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 109, 301, 21))
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: transparent;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "..."))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите число от 1 до 5"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.setupUi(self)      
        
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.value_change_func)  
        self.value_change_func(1)
        
    def value_change_func(self, n):
        if n == 1:
            self.label.setText('20')
        elif n == 2:
            self.label.setText('40')        
        elif n == 3:
            self.label.setText('60')        
        elif n == 4:
            self.label.setText('80')
        elif n == 5:
            self.label.setText('100')            
        else: 
            self.label.setText('Ошибка')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]